# automatic innodb redo log archiving

Tags: mysql, innodb, recovery, logs

We have an option to do recovery through bin-logs, but we thought recovery through bin-logs is not 99% consistent because there is no LSN(Log Sequence Number)/SCN (System Change Number) in bin-logs (Statement/mixed/row).

Is there any possibility to archive innodb-redo-logs ?

Is there any chance to do recovery by using archived Innodb Redo-logs (at the time of instance start-up) ?

Looking for valuable suggestions.

Note: I'm searching for oracle style recovery in MySQL.

Thank you all :)

Comment: MySQL is different than Oracle.  Look for tools tuned for MySQL; the best ones may not follow the pattern you are used to.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this the answer you are looking for but Percona Server has a [Log Archiving for XtraDB](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/5.6/management/log_archiving.html) feature and you can restore a backup to a [specific point in time by specifying an LSN](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.2/xtrabackup_bin/incremental_backups_with_ps_56.html#using-the-log-archiving-to-prepare-the-backup).

Just be aware of this note from the documentation:

> This feature implementation is considered BETA quality.